# AndroidRunTime NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, eclipse, noclassdeffounderror

I am busy with an Android project with the android-support-v7-appcompat library for ActionBar, I have followed the description on [Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html)

but I have got every time NoClassDefFoundError: eu.definecontent.fazilet.HomeFragment.

I can not find where is wrong in the code or configuration, maybe you can find it, I would be glad if you could help me:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity { 
    ... 
Fragment fragment = new HomeFragment(); 
    ...
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="eu.definecontent.fazilet"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" >
</uses-permission>
<application
    android:name=".FaziletApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >
    <activity
        android:name="eu.definecontent.fazilet.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name=".service.FillDailyTimetableService" />
    <activity
        android:name=".helper.DownloadManager"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
    <activity android:name=".CitySettingActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".LocationSettingActivity" />
</application>
```

and configuration are:

[image: config]

Comment: I've not really played with Fragments, but from my understanding, doesn't your parent Activity have to inherit from FragmentActivity?

Comment: @LokiSinclair no its is right op i using appcompact so need not extend FramentActivity

Comment: Most likely there is an exception thrown in the static initializer of eu.definecontent.fazilet.HomeFragment.

Comment: Are you using Proguard?

Comment: @Szymon No! I am not using Proguard,

Comment: @hgoebl what do you mean by the static initializer of ...HomeFragment, I am still not able to start it yet! thanks

Comment: Static initialization takes place if you have a block like `static { ... }` or when you initialize static members, e.g. `private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("some unparsable rubbish")`. And when static initialization encounters an error, the class is visible but you get `NoClassDefFoundError` when you want to use it.

Comment: @Xiabili : If its an error with static initializer block then you should see ExceptionInInitializerError in your stacktrace. You can follow this for further insight - http://javareferencegv.blogspot.com/2013/10/debugging-javalangnoclassdeffounderror.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [G V](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2706300/g-v) have Finally fixed that!

just added a try catch statement to initialize a static class and everythings works now!

for more info plz see this article:

[javareferencegv.blogspot.com](http://javareferencegv.blogspot.com/2013/10/debugging-javalangnoclassdeffounderror.html)